# How can I change the animation speed?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

This is the code for the animation:

```cs
private void Pass_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new()
    {
        Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)),
        From = 0,
        To = 200
    };

    ColorAnimation colorAnimation = new()
    {
        Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)),
        To = Color.FromRgb(135, 206, 250)               
    };

    Storyboard sb = new() { Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)) };


    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, passwordbox_underline);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty));

    Storyboard.SetTarget(colorAnimation, passwordbox_underline);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", Rectangle.FillProperty, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));

    sb.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
    sb.Children.Add(colorAnimation);
    sb.Begin(this);
}
```

So I have an animated rectangle. It goes from 0 with to 200 width for 1 second with the same speed. My question is how can i make it to start faster at the beginning and gradually slow it down until stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [easing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/easing-functions?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to achieve this kind of behavior.

> Easing functions allow you to apply custom mathematical formulas to your animations. For example, you may want an object to realistically bounce or behave as though it were on a spring. You could use Key-Frame or even From/To/By animations to approximate these effects but it would take a significant amount of work and the animation would be less accurate than using a mathematical formula.

For example, the exponential function (ease out) will slow down the animation towards the end.

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
   Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800),
   From = 0,
   To = 200,
   EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut, Exponent = 5}
};
```